# Postgres sorting on timestamp works on mac but not linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, travis-ci

Using Postgres 9.4

I have a posts table which relates to a users table. I'm querying for two users and 3 of their most recent posts.

```
SELECT
  "users"."id" AS "id",
  "posts"."id" AS "posts__id",
  "posts"."created_at" AS "posts__created_at"
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM accounts
  WHERE TRUE
  ORDER BY "id" ASC
  LIMIT 2
) AS "users"
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT * FROM posts
  WHERE "users".id = posts.author_id
  ORDER BY "created_at" DESC, "id" DESC
  LIMIT 3
) AS "posts" ON "users".id = "posts".author_id
```

On mac, the order is as expected.

```
"2016-04-17 18:49:15.942"
"2016-04-15 03:29:31.212"
"2016-04-13 15:07:15.119"
```

I get descending order on `created_at`, which is a `timestamptz`. However, when run on my travis build, which is Ubuntu, the ordering is stable, but neither ascending nor descending....

```
"2016-04-15 03:29:31.212"
"2016-04-13 15:07:15.119"
"2016-04-17 18:49:15.942"
```

I made user to create the databases with the same `LC_COLLATE = en_US.UTF-8` with no luck. Why on earth isn't the ordering working on travis?

Comment: It turns out this works on PG version 9.5 without modification. Alternatively, it works to add an `ORDER BY` on the outer query. I added the order clause for portability and upgraded to 9.5 just because.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, just add the order by statement under your existing statements above.
i.e.

```
SELECT
  "users"."id" AS "id",
  "posts"."id" AS "posts__id",
  "posts"."created_at" AS "posts__created_at"
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM accounts
  WHERE TRUE
  ORDER BY "id" ASC
  LIMIT 2
) AS "users"
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT * FROM posts
  WHERE "users".id = posts.author_id
  ORDER BY "created_at" DESC, "id" DESC
  LIMIT 3
) AS "posts" ON "users".id = "posts".author_id
order by posts.created_at desc
```

The order of output on postgres (and many other dbms's) cannot be guaranteed without an order by statement.

While you do indeed have order by statements, they are within sub-queries, you need the order by on the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

you may need to order the outer query too because the in join between the 2 inner queries, even when  they are ordered, won't be guaranteed.

```
SELECT
  "users"."id" AS "id",
  "posts"."id" AS "posts__id",
  "posts"."created_at" AS "posts__created_at"
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM accounts
  WHERE TRUE
  ORDER BY "id" ASC
  LIMIT 2
) AS "users"
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT * FROM posts
  WHERE "users".id = posts.author_id
  ORDER BY "created_at" DESC, "id" DESC
  LIMIT 3
) AS "posts" ON "users".id = "posts".author_id
order by "posts"."created_at" DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the actual sort order depends on both the order of `id` in the first table and the order of the `created_at` & `id` in the second one **prior** to joining them. This means the order of the first table can produce unexpected results when computing the selected values from the joined table.

To fix the sort order, you should sort the final result set by relevant columns as well.